# CURL - sending variables with GET not working

Tags: php, curl

I want to send the request to another site with GET request and should return a string value. I am using the following cURL code to achieve this but its getting failed.

```
    $user           =   'username';
    $password       =   'password';
    $sender_id      =   'myid';
    $sender_mobile  =   mobile number;
    $message_text   =   'Hi Testing SMS';
    $priority       =   'ndnd';
    $sms_type       =   'normal';
    $redirect_link  =   "http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=$user&pass=$password&sender=$sender_id&phone=$sender_mobile&text=$message_text&priority=$priority&stype=$sms_type";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$redirect_link);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    if($output == false)
    {
        echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
        echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
    }
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

But if i use the **header** its sending successfully the following is using header

```
    $user           =   'username';
    $password       =   'password';
    $sender_id      =   'myid';
    $sender_mobile  =   mobile number;
    $message_text   =   'Hi Testing SMS';
    $priority       =   'ndnd';
    $sms_type       =   'normal';
    $redirect_link  =   "http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=$user&pass=$password&sender=$sender_id&phone=$sender_mobile&text=$message_text&priority=$priority&stype=$sms_type";

    header("Location:$redirect_link");
```

where am I going wrong!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on `$sender_mobile  =   mobile number;` should be like this `$sender_mobile  =   'mobile number';`

Comment: its something like $sender_mobile = 1234567890; If this was the issue then it shouldnt have worked with 'header' too

Comment: please `echo $output;` and see whats wrong with the api you send.

Comment: its showing as - "Username/Password Incorrect or Account Deactivated", But all my credentials are perfectly fine. Its working like a charm with 'header' redirection...

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari did you solved your issue, if yes then how ?? pls reply as soon as possible

Comment: @ArshKaushal Hi since the message is plane and passing in the get parameter it would behave differently so I recommend using ```rawulrencode($message_text)``` before sending in the GET URL.

Comment: Not only with a message if you're having any other strings that need to be sent via URL please encode them via ```rawurlencode``` or ```urlencode```

Comment: i already did that but in my case there is no response is coming back not even any error. but when i run my url directly in browser it works so i think i may be somewhere in curl

Comment: i am running it from my localhost, is it the reason or any other reason or can you give me your code of curl GET/POST request or both type of request that is working it will very helpful